# Filter list filter results have no values while there are items in array list

Tags: java, android, textview, android-textwatcher

I'm trying to make a filter for a custom listview, the result of filter keeps showing all the items in the arraylist. After checking with the log, I found there are itmes in the filteredList but the results.count returns 0, this is the Log when I typed "a" from my Run window:
V/list: salad 
V/value: 0

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        return customFilter;
    }

    private Filter customFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Favorite> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                //filteredList.addAll(arrayList);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"NOTHING FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(Favorite item: arrayList){
                    if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.v("list",filteredList.get(0).getTitle());
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            Log.v("value",Integer.toString(results.count));

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            arrayList2.clear();
            arrayList2.addAll((ArrayList<Favorite>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

where I call the filter

```
searchTXT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                FavoriteFragment.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //filter(s.toString());
            }
});`
```

Comment: I added results.count = filteredList.size(); now it shows 2, but the result in the listview is still all the items

Comment: Did you [try to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1)?